# Change font style depending on value in flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I want to change font to bold and red if Value > 10. How to reach that in flextable?

My example:

```
file_path <- "c:\\temp\\test_table.docx"

df <- data.frame(
    InstanceName = c("Instance1", "Instance2", "Instance3", "Instance4", "Instance5"),
    Value = c(15, 5, 11, 0, 5)
    )

table_to_save <- flextable(df)

save_as_docx(
    table_to_save,
    path =  file.path(file_path)
)
```

What I want:

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(
  InstanceName = c("Instance1", "Instance2", "Instance3", "Instance4", "Instance5"),
  Value = c(15, 5, 11, 0, 5)
)

flextable(df) %>% 
  color(i = ~ Value > 10, j = "Value", color = "red") %>% 
  bold(i = ~ Value > 10, j = "Value")
```

[image]

Note that all of this is documented here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/format.html#usual-functions-for-formatting

Comment: thanks for your library. But i have one question to you. Can we make with ```flextable``` a table with multiple panels, like there: https://newbedev.com/tables-with-multiple-panels-in-latex-r-and-sweave ?

Comment: What is the relation between your question and the question of the OP?

Comment: I remember that question has been cross-posted on SO, github without any reprex, as in this question...

Comment: No relation. Yes, one man asked here. I tried to help him, but couldn't. Now it is interesting for me too ;)

Comment: If no data and no minimal reproducible example, I can't help!

Comment: @DavidGohel The bold part is missing in your answer.

Comment: @PaulSmith what bold part?

Comment: @DavidGohel The OP asked for *bold* and *red*!

Comment: ah ok, I miss the bold part...

Comment: @DavidGohel I try to reproduce in the future. But how to catch you...?

Comment: @manro you can open issues if you see bugs on github and you can ask question on SO, I'll answer when I have time and when I have an answer